# Do Wraiths ever get shot in the face?

Tags: stargate, episode-identification, stargate-atlantis

In *Stargate Atlantis* there are lots of scenes where Wraith get killed, but it often takes several shots to do it.

Yet as far as I can see their faces are unprotected (so that they can  feed?) so wouldn't that be the place to aim at? You wouldn't even need a futuristic weapon, as a soft-nosed bullet in the face - probably taking the back of the head off on the way out) would surely do for them.

Is there ever an episode where this happens?

Comment: I once discussed with a police officer their gun use and they said they were trained to shoot at the torso multiple times - torso because in field conditions you want to aim at the largest area instead of doing fancy shooting, and multiple times to create more sudden blood loss which seems to be what reliably stops people. Maybe soldiers are trained in a similar way? That would not answer your question, but would explain why head shots are not a usual thing.

Comment: They don't feed by eating food, they use their hands to drain the life force from their victims

Comment: I wrote and then threw away this answer, because I couldn't cite it sufficiently. But it boils down to "No, because that kind of graphic violence wasn't commonplace on TV -- even cable TV on the Sci-Fi Channel -- in 2004 when the show debuted", and "No, that didn't happen, because that's not the tone the producers were going for." 

Stargate wasn't a hyper-gritty wartime drama. It was a fun, *surprisingly* positive and upbeat in tone sci-fi show. The same characters and show that resulted in "200" *couldn't* coexist with graphically murdering their foes.

Comment: So killing is ook, so long as those killed don't get their faces mussed up? Ah well that's show business.

Comment: @TheMaskedBowler it is an upbeat show, but SG Atlantis is an upbeat show that also features man-eating human/bug hybrids, a soldier who cannibalizes said hybrids to collect a substance that gives him super powers, body horror when people transform into bugs and vice versa and similarly unsavoury stuff. I am not sure they excluded head shots because they somehow thought those specifically would have crossed a line.

Comment: @ various commenters: Yes, basically, there's a big difference. To use an example from a different medium: there's an *obvious* difference between, say, GoldenEye 007's "low-polygon marionette-looking guard has a blocky red splotch and falls over and vanishes after being shot" death and  "Sniper Elite-style anatomically-correct-in-gruesome-detail-slow-motion-exploding-bodyparts" death. I'm willing to wager a non-trivial percentage of the TV audience *doesn't* want to see realistic violence in their sci-fi show. :P

Comment: Points taken though of course it wouldn't *have*  to be quite as messy as I suggested. The back of the head coming off is "optional", and a facial wound alone wouldn't make a Wraith noticeably more hideous than they are anyway.